# How To Check My Current Version of FFMPEG

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have FFMPEG installed on 2 different servers.  On one of the servers, i run into an issue every time i try to convert m4v files where ffmpeg just processes the file indefinitely.  When   I take the same source file and try to run it on the other server it seems to work just fine.  Both servers are running the same version of GNU/Linux.  Some one suggested i check to see if the same version of ffmpeg is installed on the servers, so my question to you all is, "how do i check my ffmpeg version?"

Thanks!

Comment: This is a place to ask things, but it would help you greatly in the future if you became comfortable with e.g. `man ffmpeg`, or in this case even just `ffmpeg`, which informs you to run `ffmpeg -h` for more help. Also a package manager could give you the answer. That was for the terminal (well, the package manager might very well be GUI based), and I'm certain that the man pages are available in some graphical way as well if one is not comfortable with the terminal. Googling on "ffmpeg version" also gives a first-page answer. I'm not trying to be snarky, but "teach a man to fish", etc.

Comment: It's a useful question and the upvoted answer below is what is called for Daniel. Unix help pages involve pages and pages of scrolling. For larger utilities they are not useful unless one has fifteen minutes to half an hour to study them.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Call it with the right command line flag:

```
ffmpeg -version
```

For a full list of the underlying libraries, just call ffmpeg without any option:

```
ffmpeg
```

Comment: This does not work in ubuntu 14.04 as I am using ffmpeg libraries but there is no ffmpeg application.

Comment: the question is about the ffmpeg-binary, not the libav*-header or -lib.so files.

Comment: @kkron in ubuntu 14.04 there is no `ffmpg`, as it was replaced by `avconv` so  you should do `avconv -version`

Comment: @kkron if you installed it from a package manage, simply look there

Answer (score 11):

Run `ffmpeg -version` and inspect the output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
               ^^^^^
```

#### Git versions

Sometimes you will get something like this rather than an actual release version:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
                              ^^^^^^^
```

In which case it was a development build. To find the release version after which it was taken, take the 7 characters at the end of the version tag (i.e. `4a11a6f`) and insert them into this URL:

> https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/blob_plain/4a11a6f:/RELEASE

The response is "4.3.git", meaning this build was from the 4.3 release branch.

---

Older versions may have a different format:

```
ffmpeg version N-55702-g920046a Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
                        ^^^^^^^
```

Here the commit id is `920046a`, which gives a release branch of 2.0.

#### Package queries

If your current ffmpeg was installed via a package manager, you can also look there:

```
$ dpkg -s ffmpeg | grep Version
Version: 7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2
           ^^^^^
```

```
$ apt list --installed ffmpeg
Listing... Done
ffmpeg/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
                                            ^^^^^
```

```
$ rpm -q ffmpeg
ffmpeg-4.3.1-4.el8.x86_64
       ^^^^^
```

```
$ yum list -q installed ffmpeg
Installed Packages
ffmpeg.x86_64                  1:4.3.1-4.el8                  @epel-multimedia
                                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: (+1) This should really be the accepted answer!