# Will FFmpeg produce the same binary output file every time?

Tags: ffmpeg

Assuming the source file did not change and the same FFmpeg version is being used, will the output file always be the same?

Say I have a source file that has an extension of AVI. If I convert it to MP4 using default FFmpeg settings, will each FFmpeg run produce bit identical files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qualified answer is yes. The usual differences are due to the version strings embedded by encoders and muxers. Adding `-bitexact` will suppress those.

However, some encoders like x265 are non-deterministic in multi-threaded encoding.

There are a few other niche cases like some DSP routines on PPC and Altivec architectures, and a few pixel format conversion routines. `-bitexact` has an effect here too, in which routines are selected.

FFmpeg has an automated regression testing suite, whose public results can be viewed at [fate.ffmpeg.org](http://fate.ffmpeg.org).

Almost all of the tests are checked against hashes of reference runs. Which basically requires bit exactness.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the codecs and options used.

1. command `ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny_480p_stereo.avi out.mp4` produces the same binary files. But if you add bitrate options

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny_480p_stereo.avi -maxrate 500k -bufsize 500k out.mp4
```

you may get different results even with `-bitexact`.

So encoding with x264 (which is default for `.mp4` if libx264 available), multiple threads (by default the number of threads is [selected automatically](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Codec-Options)) and bitrate options may produce different binaries.

2. You may need to make sure that the **codec** versions (not only ffmpeg version) are the same as ffmpeg with the same version could be configured to use different versions of libx264 which can result in different binaries across encodings of the same file. Unfortunately [there is no easy way](https://superuser.com/questions/1348706/how-to-check-the-version-of-codecs-in-ffmpeg) to check codec versions.